# Getting error Unable to compile class for JSP when running playground2

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am going through [local authenticator example](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/develop/writing-a-custom-local-authenticator/) and at step 14, after I press 'Authorize', getting exception

```
[2021-02-02 18:13:41,087] [0528806c-f8f8-4df5-abca-5f47c3972b24] ERROR 
{org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/authenticationendpoint]. 
[default]} - Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path 
[/authenticationendpoint] threw exception [Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [25] in the jsp file: [/includes/localize.jsp]
Duplicate local variable BUNDLE
22: <%@ page import="java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets" %>
23: <%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
24: <%
25:     String BUNDLE = 
"org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint.i18n.Resources";
26:     ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE, request.getLocale(), 
new
27:             EncodedControl(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()));
28: %>
```

I am running WSO2 5.11 and Tomcat 7.0.107.

Comment: This JSP seems fine. Can u check whether you're getting this error with the default basic authenticator? if this an issue with the authentication endpoint then you should get the same error in the basic authenticator.

Comment: I think it has more to do with my Tomcat configuration, but with so many possibilities where this might happen, I was hoping someone would help here.